# What redirect to use for mobile version of site?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, mobile, seo

I have asp.net application. and I have created mobile version of it which is separate IIS application.

Example:

http://sitename.com and mobile version is http://m.sitename.com

What page redirect better to use? Response.Redirect(http://m.sitename.com); or is there better way?

I want to make sure this redirect won't effect the site SEO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

definitely you must use the non permanent redirect, 302.

```
responce.Clear();
responce.StatusCode = 302;
responce.Status = "302 Temporarily Moved";
responce.RedirectLocation = url;
```

also as

```
Response.Redirect("http://m.buycarandsellcar.com", false);
```

you can also read : http://www.dotnetperls.com/redirect